# White space appearing between images in a table

Tags: html, whitespace

I have the following HTML:

```
<table width="700" align="center" style="border:0">
    <tr style="border:0"> <td> <img src="images\1.png" /> </td></tr>
    <tr style="border:0"> <td> <img src="images\2.png" /> </td> </tr>
    <tr style="border:0"> <td> <img src="images\3.png" /></td> </tr>
    <tr style="border:0"> <td> <img src="images\4.png" /> </td></tr>
    <tr style="border:0"> <td> <img src="images\5.png" /> </td></tr>
    <tr style="border:0"> <td> <img src="images\6.png" /> </td></tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that white space is appearing between the images. How do I remove it?

Comment: there're no spaces, I removed all the spaces, and still white spaces between rows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<table width="700" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr><td> <img src="images\1.png" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td> <img src="images\2.png" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td> <img src="images\3.png" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td> <img src="images\4.png" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td> <img src="images\5.png" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td> <img src="images\6.png" /></td></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: just an observation on your answer (apart from the missing opening angle bracket), you ought to highlight the difference in some way :)

Comment: There should be an explanation along with the example.

Answer (score 4):

first add cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" to your table element

```
  <table width="700" align="center" style="border:0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

and remove spaces between td and img tags

Answer (score 3):

You could try not using a table, so you'd have ...

```
<img src="images/1.png" />
...
<img src="images/6.png />
```

and use some css to make them block elements with no margin/padding

or you could use css on your table like this ...

```
<style>
    table { border-collapse: collapse; }
</style>
```

you would also need to add a couple of attributes to your table

```
<table .... cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" ...>
```

all trying to get rid of padding.margin on your table.

But IMO for what you're trying to do, going the straight `<img />` tag route with css would be better.

Answer (score 2):

```
<table cellspacing="0">
```

should solve it :)

Answer (score 2):

change `<td> <img src="images\1.png" /> </td></tr>` to `<td><img src="images\1.png" /></td></tr>`, set cellspacing and cellpadding to 0, and check

Answer (score 1):

Add to your style

```
border-spacing:0px;
```

Comment: ...and `border-collapse: collapse` for any `border-width` other than 0.

Answer (score 0):

How are you archiving your data? Thought the server?

In some text editors you can make searches with regular expression. Then you can do this:

Search:

```
<td>(\s*)(.*?)(\s*)</td>
```

Replace:

```
<td>$2</td>
```

Searches for:

```
<td>[WHITE SPACE IF ANY]STRING[WHITE SPACE IF ANY]</td>
```

And replaces it with:

```
<td>STRING</td>
```

Comment: whitespace in HTML is ignored by the browser. I think AMH was asking how to remove the gaps between his images.

Answer (score 0):

For Transitional Doctype, most of the suggested solutions in the internet works.

But for Strict Doctype, the following will remove the white line between two images in `<TD>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> <html> <head>

<title>Test</title>

</head>    
<body>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

<tr><td><img style="display:block;" src="../images/test_blue.jpg"></td></tr>

<tr><td><img style="display:block;" src="../images/test_green.jpg"></td></tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Want to post the screenshot here but insufficient reputation post to do so.

Answer (score 0):

**Removing white spaces appearing between images in a table which is part of the blog:**

For those who came here after facing this problem on blogs. I faced same problem. However my table was part of a blog on blogger. I had images each in a cell of the table. I tried cellspacing, cellpadding and many other attributes and parameters but nothing worked. In case of blog, in the blog template these changes were made:

- Under ".post-body img" value of "padding: 10px" changed to "padding: 0px" [This removed verticle space between images]
- Under ".post-body" value of "line-height: 1.4;" changed to "line-height: 0;" [This removed space between table rows]

More detailed answer here:

http://xomisse.com/blog/tutorial-remove-spaces-between-images-in-blogger/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```css
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also some mobile browsers may create white spaces between images without width and height attribute. Set your images sizes to td and set your images w 100% h 100%.

```
<table width="700" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr><td width="100" height="100"> <img src="images\1.png" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td width="100" height="100"> <img src="images\2.png" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td width="100" height="100"> <img src="images\3.png" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td width="100" height="100"> <img src="images\4.png" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td width="100" height="100"> <img src="images\5.png" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td width="100" height="100"> <img src="images\6.png" /></td></tr>
</table>

<style>
    table td img { width:100%; height:100%; }
</style>
```